# iOS and RestKit: How to get a text/html response right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

I have tried several StackOverflow questions, and I caanot find the correct answer on this. I am using the POSTMAN plugin for Chrome to check my REST calls and I cannot figure out why I cannot read the response. In the comments you will see all the different attempts I have made to get the response.

```
NSDictionary* session_params = @{SESSION_USERNAME_KEY:SESSION_USERNAME_VALUE, SESSION_PASSWORD_KEY:SESSION_PASSWORD_VALUE};
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:SESSION_URL];
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
//GET THE **** THING TO INTERPRET A TEXT response

//[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
//[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/html"];
//[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
//[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];
//[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];
//[objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"text/html"];

//END
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:SESSION_URL parameters:session_params];


RKObjectRequestOperation* operation = [objectManager
                                       objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation* operation, RKMappingResult* result)
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"RESULT [%@]", result);
                                       }
                                       failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                           NSLog(@"ERROR [%@]", error);
                                       }];

    [operation start];
```

---

I think the most irritating thing is that the stuff I need is contained in the NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion value. It is a session key I require.

OUTPUT:

> E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:547 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>       "application/json"
>   )}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x1c52aed0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJCbG8uUmVnQWxlcnQuQnJva2VyIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9CbG8uUmVnQWxlcnQuQVBJL2FwaSIsIm5iZiI6MTM5MjY0MTY2MSwiZXhwIjoxMzkyNjQ1MjYxLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IkJ1dHRvbnMiLCJyb2xlIjoiUmVnQWxlcnRDb25zdW1lciJ9.JCTMGJRKlOxEtNrcGodpce-tqsRS4zlApNisKQW6iSw, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://..., NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
>       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>       "application/json"
>   )}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}
>   2014-02-17 14:54:20.808 AppName[5600:6403] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:213 POST 'http://...' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.0000s mapping=0.0000s total=0.1925s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>       "application/json"
>   )}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x1c52aed0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJCbG8uUmVnQWxlcnQuQnJva2VyIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9CbG8uUmVnQWxlcnQuQVBJL2FwaSIsIm5iZiI6MTM5MjY0MTY2MSwiZXhwIjoxMzkyNjQ1MjYxLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IkJ1dHRvbnMiLCJyb2xlIjoiUmVnQWxlcnRDb25zdW1lciJ9.JCTMGJRKlOxEtNrcGodpce-tqsRS4zlApNisKQW6iSw, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://..., NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
>       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>       "application/json"
>   )}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

**CODE THAT WORKED**
Thanks to Wain for pointing me on the correct path there. I am a little disappointed that RestKit cannot handle such a simple request, and I need RestKit because this is just a session token to calling the other methods, but whatever works I guess:

```
NSDictionary* session_params = @{SESSION_USERNAME_KEY:SESSION_USERNAME_VALUE, SESSION_PASSWORD_KEY:SESSION_PASSWORD_VALUE};

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:SESSION_URL];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:SESSION_URL parameters:session_params];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString* response = [operation responseString];
    NSLog(@"response: %@",response);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
}];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit:

> "Expected content type {( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "application/json" )}, got text/html"

tells you that you have told RestKit to expect `form-urlencoded` or `json`, but that the server is returning html.

You *would* probably want to use `setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType` with JSON mime type to tell the server what you want back. But, in this case you probably just shouldn't be using RestKit.

RestKit is for mapping arbitrary JSON / XML data into your data model. You just have a key coming back. No mapping is required. So, don't use RestKit, use AFNetworking instead (which you have full access to because RestKit uses it internally.

Comment: Thank you for that - I have put the working code with the question so that I have it preserved in case I need it, or someone else has the same issue. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Wain and Quintin, this was quite useful to me :)

I think some names changed in more recent versions of `Restkit` or `AFNetworking`. I used `AFNetworking` as explained in other answers since the server did not return `json` but empty `plain/text` instead. This was only on a particular endpoint where I was looking for a token in the headers of the response.

Sharing my piece of code here too:

```objective-c
-(void) find_some_token_with_success:(void (^)(AFRKHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(AFRKHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"];

    AFRKHTTPClient *client = [AFRKHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [client setDefaultHeader:@"some_custom_header" value:@"some_custom_value"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/api/v1/some_non_json_endpoint" parameters:nil];

    AFRKHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFRKHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    [operation start];
}
```

Then I used something like this to get the header I was looking for:

```objective-c
-(void) get_the_token:(void (^)(NSString *token))withTokenCallback failure:(void (^)(AFRKHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {
    [self xsrftoken_with_success:^(AFRKHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *token = [self get_the_token_from_response:[operation response]];
        withTokenCallback(token);
    } failure:failure];
}

-(NSString *) get_the_token_from_response: (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
{
    NSDictionary *headerDictionary = response.allHeaderFields;
    NSString *token = [headerDictionary objectForKey:@"SOME-TOKEN-KEY"];
    return token;
}
```

So all of this can simply be used like this:

```objective-c
- (void)testGetSometokenInARequest
{
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Query timed out."];

    [[SomeRequestWithoutJsonResponse alloc]
     get_the_token:^(NSString *token) {
         [expectation fulfill];
         NSLog(@"token: %@", token);
         // this token should be 100 characters long
         XCTAssertTrue([token length] == 100);
     }
     failure:^(AFRKHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
     }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10.0 handler:nil];
}
```

In other words, `get_the_token` takes a callback with the desired token and a failure callback.

Make sure you still include `<RestKit/RestKit>` so you have access to Restkit's `AFNetowkring` :)

---

### Alternative working solution using restkit:

[RestKit: How to handle empty response.body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810556/restkit-how-to-handle-empty-response-body)

And you register a serializer for that kind of Mimetype like this:

```objective-c
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];
```