# How to post without post data using RestKit

Tags: objective-c, post, null, restkit, nsmutabledictionary

I was looking for a way to map an empty object to be posted to an endpoint. The call needs to be a `POST`, but there shouldn't be any data posted to the endpoint (empty body), it's only about calling the endpoint directly without data.

I've tried doing the same trick as in [RestKit: How to handle empty response.body?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21810596/1092815) but using `RKRequestDescriptor` instead.

Doing so leads to following error when using `postData:nil` in `RKObjectMapping`'s `postObject` method:

> Uncaught exception: `RKRequestDescriptor` objects must be initialized with a mapping whose target class is `NSMutableDictionary`, got 'NSNull' (see `[RKObjectMapping requestMapping]`);

Using `NSNull` for the `RKRequestDescriptor`'s mapping seems to work, but `nil` seems to fail the mapping action.

Answer (score 1):

As the error mentions, it's looking for an `NSMutableDictionary` for the mapping action. so using an empty `NSMutableDictionary` like `@{}` instead of `nil` for `postObject` does the trick.

```objective-c
AFRKHTTPClient *client = [self getClient];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSNull class]];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:
 [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                       objectClass:[NSNull class]
                                       rootKeyPath:nil
                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny]];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSNull class]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:
 [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                              method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                         pathPattern:nil
                                             keyPath:nil
                                         statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];

 [objectManager postObject:@{} // <-- this works, but nil doesn't
                         path:@"/api/some/endpoint"
                   parameters:nil
                      success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                          // succes code here
                      } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                          // failure code here
                      }];
```